# Loop animation for css

Tags: css, animation

Please how can I get the animation below to continue looping without javascript, just CSS and HTML. So that when it gets to 7, it will start all over from one again and continues that way until the page is closed. I have been on this for over 3 hours. I will appreciate if anyone can please guide me on this.

Thank you in advance.

```css
.merry {
  font-family: "Georgia", serif;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
}

.merry-text {
  left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 50px;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
}

.merry-text:nth-of-type(1) {
  animation-name: rotate;
  animation-duration: 2.5s;
  animation-delay: 1s;

}

.merry-text:nth-of-type(2) {
  animation-name: rotate;
  animation-duration: 2.5s;
  animation-delay: 3s;

}

.merry-text:nth-of-type(3) {
  animation-name: rotate;
  animation-duration: 2.5s;
  animation-delay: 5s;

}
.merry-text:nth-of-type(4) {
  animation-name: rotate;
  animation-duration: 2.5s;
  animation-delay: 7s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.merry-text:nth-of-type(5) {
  animation-name: rotate;
  animation-duration: 2.5s;
  animation-delay: 9s;
}
.merry-text:nth-of-type(6) {
  animation-name: rotate;
  animation-duration: 2.5s;
  animation-delay: 11s;
}
.merry-text:nth-of-type(7) {
  animation-name: rotate;
  animation-duration: 2.5s;
  animation-delay: 13s;
}
@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate3d(0, 50px, 0);
  }
  
  20%, 80% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate3d(0, -25px, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<p class="merry">
  <span class="merry-text">circle 1</span>
  <span class="merry-text">circle 2</span>
  <span class="merry-text">circle 3 </span>
    <span class="merry-text">circle 4</span>
    <span class="merry-text">circle 5</span>
    <span class="merry-text">circle 6</span>  
<span class="merry-text">circle 7</span>
</p>
```

Comment: `animation-iteration-count: infinite;` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-iteration-count

Comment: Yes, I added that but the text are overlapping when it is added.

Comment: Then it's likely your other animation values need adjusting.

Comment: instead of animating individual elements, animate the whole container in such a way that only one is visible at a time and you see the rolling effect, then add this infinite property to that animation, hope it helps.

Comment: Could you please help if you can.

Comment: Thank you so much, i was able to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply by using this:

```
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center. –